# modifying font size using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Is there any way to change the font size of terminal window(GNOME or KDE) from inside a shell script
Actually I want to display a file in a particular format on screens of all sizes.
Can i do it using scripts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For KDE, you can use **dcop** to set your font size.

For example:

```
dcop konsole-8540 session-6 setFont Monospace,20,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
```

(the 20 in the example above is the font size)

Answer (score 0):

I for one would surely not want a shell script (or any other program for that matter) to change my terminal settings! If it were to find a way to do so, I would use it exactly once and them remove it from my machine.

Seriously: This is something you *should not do*, because the user will probably have set his or her screen size to the way it is for a reason that is probably better than yours for changing it. Consider handicapped people who might need a specific font or very large letters to be able to read the screen at all.

Better try and make your application suitable for any terminal layout - there are variables for telling you how many characters wide and how many lines high your current environment is.

Comment: Did he ask if he should do it, or how to do it?

Comment: Sometimes looking at things from a different angle helps, so I wrote this answer. I usually appreciate constructive criticism - so I offered some here.